# displaying a page via multiple variables in url

Tags: php, url, get

a sample of my link would look like this "/jet/index.php?year=2011&quarter=Q1"
now i need to display the page that contains the first months in quarter one of year 2011.
/jet/index.php?year=2011&quarter=Q1 would display april may june. and so on.

my code looks like this

```
 <a href="index.php?year=2011&quarter=Q1">
    <a href="index.php?year=2011&quarter=Q2">
    <a href="index.php?year=2011&quarter=Q1">
    <a href="index.php?year=2011&quarter=Q4">
```

my home page, which is the year 2012 works just fine, here is the code

```
 <?php 
$quarters = array('Q1' => 'firstq2012.php', 'Q2' => 'secondq2012.php', 'Q3' => 'thirdq2012.php', 'Q4' => 'fourthq2012.php');
if(isset($_GET['quarter'])) {
    if(in_array($_GET['quarter'], array_keys($quarters))) {
        include_once $quarters[$_GET['quarter']];
    } else {
        header('Location: 404.php');
    }
} else {
    include_once $quarters['Q3'];
}
?>
```

i need your help on how would the transition from 2012 to 2011 would look like (i do it via a link)

thanks!

Comment: Hard to interpret your problem

Comment: Before you go online: http://www.aeonity.com/frost/how-preventing-remote-file-inclusion-exploits-php

Answer (score 0):

I would change your code completely...

code to check and include the quarters

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['year']) && isset($_GET['quarter'])) {
 // get params
 $year = (strlen($_GET['year']) == 4 && is_numeric($_GET['year']) ? (int)$_GET['year'] : date('Y'));
 $quarter = (substr($_GET['quarter'], 0, 1) == 'Q' && is_numeric(substr($_GET['quarter'], 1, 1)) ? (int)substr($_GET['quarter'], 1, 1) : ceil(date('n') / 4));

 $quartalsNumberToName = array(
  1 => 'first',
  2 => 'second',
  3 => 'third',
  4 => 'fourth'
 );
 $filename = $quartalsNumberToName[$quarter] .'q'. $year .'.php';

 if(file_exists($filename)) {
   include_once($filename);
 } else {
   header('Location: 404.php');
   exit;
 }
} else {
 include_once($quartalsNumberToNume[3] .'q2012.php';
}
?>
```

code to generate the links:

```
<ul>
<?php
// the start year
$yearStart = 2011;

for($i = $yearStart; $i <= date('Y'); $i++) {
  for($j = 1; $j <= 4; $j++) {
?>
  <li><a href="index.php?year=<?php echo($i); ?>&amp;quarter=Q<?php echo($j); ?>">Year <?php echo($i); ?>, Quarter <?php echo($j); ?></a></li>
<?php
  }
}
?>
</ul>
```

untested... but should work.